# Unable to make a logic to disable a button according to the date in php

Tags: php, html

I want the "Buy now!" button disabled if last ordered date is within 30 days.
The variable $val["order_date"]  contains the date of the day the user pressed the "Buy Now!" (ordered).

For example if the user pressed the "Buy Now!" on 2017/06/16. The  $val["order_date"] will contain "2017/06/16" and willbe displayed as a ordered date.

I want to disable the "Buy Now!" button if a month(30 days) hasn't passed. So if the order_date is "2017/06/16", 
and the user tries to click on the "Buy now!" on "2017/06/28" the button will be disabled (Only alert dialog shows). 
However, the button will be clickable if 30 days passes from "2017/06/16". Some examples or tips would be great ! I would love to hear from you!

```
<?php 
The Logic to check if 30 days passed might look something like this.
if (Did 30 days passed from $val["order_date"] ?) {
$isDisabled = "";
} else {
$isDisabled = "disabled";
}
?>

<table>
    <tr>
       <th>ordered date</th><td class="date">:</td><td><?= $val["order_date"] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="button"<?=$isDisabled ?>>Buy Now!</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this sample code

```
<?php

   // Asuming today as 28th june 2017
    $today = date('2017-06-28');

    // Asuming your buying date is 16th june 2017
   $buyedDate = date('2017-06-16');

   // Take what is the date of last 30 days of today's date.
   $tDays = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-30 days',strtotime($today)));

   // Now check is buyed date is greater then last 30 days then disable otherwise enable.
   if(strtotime($buyedDate) > strtotime($tDays)){
        echo 'DISABLE';
    } else {
        echo 'ENABLE';
    }
?>
```

A live example sandbox

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/14091c690e1e7e4ebcb46c642003f586d38d98d2

Comment: Perhaps you should explain *why* he should use this... simply pasting some code and saying "use this" does not help the asker actually learn anything.

Comment: Thanks @JasonBassett for the suggestion. I will try to make the most of it. But I didn't said "use this" in my answer. I alrerady explained the code sample by commenting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d")); //$val["order_date"]
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$days = $interval->format('%a');

if ($days < 30) {
    $isDisabled = "";
} else {
    $isDisabled = "disabled";
}
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ordered date</th><td class="date">:</td><td><?= $val["order_date"] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="button"<?= $isDisabled ?>>Buy Now!</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this -

```
$someDate = new \DateTime('2017/06/16 0:0:1');
$now = new \Datetime();

if($someDate->diff($now)->days > 30) {
   echo 'The date was more than 30 days ago.';
} else {
   echo 'You need to wait atleast 30 days before placing new order.';
}
```